# in goLang, who to understand *var.Type

Tags: go

```
 11 func Map(value string) *list.List {
 12 }
```

for example as above.
"list" is var name, List is goLang built-in type.
how do I understand *list.List ?

Is it a List pointer that with name list?

Also, if my understanding is right, what is the element's type in this list? It is not defined.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Function types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types)
>
> A function type denotes the set of all functions with the same
>   parameter and result types. The value of an uninitialized variable of
>   function type is nil.
>
> ```
> FunctionType   = "func" Signature .
> Signature      = Parameters [ Result ] .
> Result         = Parameters | Type .
> Parameters     = "(" [ ParameterList [ "," ] ] ")" .
> ParameterList  = ParameterDecl { "," ParameterDecl } .
> ParameterDecl  = [ IdentifierList ] [ "..." ] Type .
> ```
>
> Within a list of parameters or results, the names (IdentifierList)
>   must either all be present or all be absent. If present, each name
>   stands for one item (parameter or result) of the specified type and
>   all non-blank names in the signature must be unique. If absent, each
>   type stands for one item of that type. Parameter and result lists are
>   always parenthesized except that if there is exactly one unnamed
>   result it may be written as an unparenthesized type.

---

> [Package list](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/)
>
> ```
> import "container/list"
> ```
>
> Package list implements a doubly linked list.
>
> [type Element](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#Element)
>
> ```
> type Element struct {
>
>         // The value stored with this element.
>         Value interface{}
>         // contains filtered or unexported fields
> }
> ```
>
> Element is an element of a linked list.
>
> [type List](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#List)
>
> ```
> type List struct {
>         // contains filtered or unexported fields
> }
> ```
>
> List represents a doubly linked list. The zero value for List is an
>   empty list ready to use.

---

`list` is a package name. The result type `*list.List` is a pointer to type `list.List`. The elements of type `list.List` are of type `list.Element`. For example,

```
package main

import "container/list"

func Map(value string) *list.List { return nil }

func main() {}
```